POST and GET responses in NextJS without using API route
I have a bit strange of a setup. The user sends form and under the hood nextjs talks to external service and gets special link. I redirect user to that special link and after some manipulations, external service essentially redirects user back to my server but with POST data. So i need to use that data and display regular page to user. Something like that:
export function Page() {
    const {name, email, data} = usePostData();

    // some serverside functions here

    return <div>Hello: {name}</div>
}


